# How can I change the border attributes for the week days table in a Richfaces Rich Calendar?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

When using rich:calendar from richfaces, how can we change the border attributes regarding the table that is generated for the "week days".

Answer (score 1):

You can override the component style classes (css), [here](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_calendar.html) you have the list of classes for the component.

You could also create your custom classes and assign them to the component via the style attributes, for instance: attribute **style** of rich:calendar.

Another option is to modify the skin parameters, [here](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_1_X/Developer_Guide/en-US/html/chap-Developer_Guide-Skinning_and_theming.html#sect-Developer_Guide-Skinning_overview-Skin_parameter_tables) is the jboss reference to customize skins. I think the skin parameter for what you need is `.rich-calendar-cell`